# Conditional property binding between the values of two WPF Sliders

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two sliders laid out in XAML:

```
<Border Background="Black">
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFB13232" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="800" Height="600" />
        <Slider x:Name="bigvalue" Orientation="Vertical" Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01" Value="1" />
        <Slider x:Name="smallvalue" Orientation="Vertical" Maximum="1" LargeChange="0.1" SmallChange="0.01"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

...and I would like to achieve the following behavior: if `bigvalue.Value`, during sliding, reaches `smallvalue.Value` and I keep sliding down, `smallvalue.Value` should be updated, similar to a "collision detection" between the sliders' cursors.

(background: these will control top position and bottom position of an object that will be drawn in the image, and this object should not have a negative (top_position - bottom_position) dimension.)

I thought about using Property Binding, but my use case calls for a conditional property binding, and I'm confused as how to achieve that.

Also, for the moment, I preferred not to get into the realm of home-made WPF Range Sliders (sliders with two cursors), although I agree that it would be the "right" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `Range` view model class that implements the desired behaviour:

```
public class Range : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private double minimum;
    public double Minimum
    {
        get { return minimum; }
        set
        {
            minimum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Minimum");

            if (Maximum < Minimum)
            {
                Maximum = Minimum;
            }
        }
    }

    private double maximum;
    public double Maximum
    {
        get { return maximum; }
        set
        {
            maximum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Maximum");

            if (Minimum > Maximum)
            {
                Minimum = Maximum;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and then bind the two Sliders to the two properties `Minimum` and `Maximum`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.DataContext>
        <local:Range/>
    </StackPanel.DataContext>
    <Slider Value="{Binding Minimum}"/>
    <Slider Value="{Binding Maximum}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That is interesting. I will digest this for a moment, but I think I will go one step further and bind the sliders directly to the correspondent properties of my object, and put the logic in the object itself.